# Admin page cant be reached on Magento 2 installation on wamp server

Tags: magento2

After installation on local wamp server the admin page cannot be found when i click on the 'Launch Magento Admin' or follow the admin address. I do get a home page when i visit http://localhost/magento/
Magento version 2.3.9 and wamp version 3.1.9

Comment: if you go to http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin do you get it if so you your rewrites are not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

First thing Magento 2 have launched there 2.3.2 Version till now, how you installed 2.3.9.
Please check your Magento Version by going to this file

```
Your-Instance\composer.json
```

And Check Version Here

[image]

Now You have to Check Your Backend Link by Going on following path as:

```
Your-Instance\app\etc\env.php
```

and Check

[image]

Now this Keyboard belongs to your URL like, Now My URL is

```
magentoexampleinstance.com/backend
```

Is it understand ?

Comment: It is version 2.3.3 as you stated, the link localhost/magento/index.php/admin does not work so how do I fix/edit the rewrites? thanks

Comment: \app\etc\env.php   reads                                                                                                   <?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin_1p3xjr'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '9a78b96b15266db8cbf5841ca022aa82'